# Forge BIM360 API: New Project Service Activation problem

Tags: autodesk-forge

Today (10/29/2021) we started having problems creating new projects via the Forge BIM360 API.  We are using a tool we created and have used to create hundreds of projects previously.  We are finding that we can create the project but most project services, including doc management and project management, show the activation spinning wheel.  We are able to create a project and activate a service manually.  This problem happened previously (months / years ago) but hasn't been an issue of late.  Any advice?

Comment: My colleague reported the same issue on Friday; i.e., all services is spinning under Services tab. We reported it to the product team. But it went back normal later on the same day. Do you still have the issue? Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment Mikako.  I checked the following day and found that the services had activated on my test projects.  In addition we are able to create projects again using Forge and have services activate in a timely manner.  It's helpful to know that others experienced similar behavior.  One thought:  I did not check health.autodesk.com on Friday to see if problems were identified.

Comment: I do not see the note left on health.autodesk.com about admin API. I will remind the product team for future. Hopefully once we have the newer version of admin API, it will be stable. Sorry once again for causing the interruption.